# Advanced Search with Custom Currency

Tags: currency, advanced-search

I have made an implemented a custom currency, and everything seems to work perfectly!

Except for the advanced search.  It uses the Base Currency (USD) and not the custom currency I created myself.  I would like for people to enter the custom currency, as they never see USD on the store and don't know the exchange rate.

Is there a setting somewhere, or does this require extensive coding?

I have an idea that I could divide whatever number they put in by the exchange rate, but that is the LEAST preferred solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, with 'created a custom currency' I gather that is a new attribute you created?

Comment: Custom currency, as in, instead of everything being USD, the currency that is shown on the store is "Points", a currency I made up.  The advanced search, if you enter 15, searches 15 USD for items, not the "point equivalent" or 15.

Comment: Hi, That does not answer the question. Is this an attribute? Or id it dynamically calculated on display?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  In Magento you can make currencies, so custom currency is a currency, and currency is not considered an attribute....  If you're talking about the price range checker, it is an attribute.  I looked in attribute settings for a place to change what currency it uses to compare but that didn't exist.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad and I don't feel able to reproduce this fast.

1. Question is: Why do you use USD as base currency and not yours? If it is used everywhere this is obvious to me :-)
2. you might want to rewrite `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`. There are a lot of currency methods in you want to check and if they return USD, you might want to rewrite them.